# How to compare a pointer value with NULL in C

Tags: c

I was writing a function which removes a node in a linked list, whose input is a pointer to a linked list. If the function removes a linked list that has only one node, the function will make the pointer point to NULL. Here's part of the code:

```
void remove(dlinkNode_t *start){
    //some previous code
    if(start->next==NULL){//meaning we're removing the head of the linked list
        dlinkNode_t current=start;  //get a temp pointer to point at this node
        start=NULL;    //make start point to null
        free(current); //free the head
        return;
    }
    // More code
```

In main I created a linked list with one node, and passed this linked list to remove function to free it. Here's the code:

```
int main(){
    dlinkNode_t *node1=create();  //creates a node and make node1 point at it
    remove(node1);  //now node1 should point at NULL
    if(node1==NULL)
        printf("hi");
    return 0;
}
```

But I didn't see the hi printed. I don't know why the if statement didn't pass. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A new copy of the pointer is made in the local scope of `remove`. Any changes you make to the pointer will only be visible in that scope. Any changes that you make to the value being pointed to by a pointer will return to the calling scope.

You can solve this problem in one of two ways :

- Return the edited pointer

  ```
  node1 = remove(node1);
  ```

  and make the change in remove as well.

  ```
  dlinkNode_t * remove(dlinkNode_t *start){
      //some previous code
      //Function code
      return start;
  ```
- Or you can pass a pointer to the pointer start and then manipulate that pointer.

  Function call :

  ```
  remove(&node1);
  ```

  Function definition :

  ```
  void remove(dlinkNode_t **start){
      //some previous code
      if((*start)->next==NULL){ // meaning we're removing 
                                // the head of the linked list
          dlinkNode_t current=**start; //get a temp pointer
                                       // to point at this node
          **start=NULL;  //make start point to null
          free(current); //free the head
  ```

Comment: Oh I see I didn't realize that. So Does that mean in the structure of this remove function there's no way to make *start point to a NULL? If so how can I do that? Thanks!